# offers no sympathy

Tags: writing

I wrote this:

> The man does a couple of breathing exercises to calm himself before
> take-off. The woman seated next to him gives him a look.
>
> Man: *Sorry. I'm just a little nervous about flying.*
>
> **The woman offers no sympathy.** The plane starts moving.

Is the sentence in bold okay and understood? If not what else could I write to say that she couldn't care less and that she's annoyed with him?

Comment: It is understood. You could also write "She looks away as the plane starts moving."

Answer (score -2):

The verb tense is a bit odd here. And you really need to add something else if you are going to write at all well here.

Man: Sorry... flying.
Woman: Shakes her head and turns back to her magazine.

Offering no sympathy is in itself a non-thing. That phrase usually is followed with a 'but' or something else to indicate what she did do.